# Navigating back from other app breaks click handler

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

For our company we have a lot of devices rolled out with Mobicontrol Soti. This allows us to lock the device in something called a kiosk mode which disables the use of the homescreen and provides a custom screen that only have a set off apps we can decide.

One of the provided apps is a Ionic app that opens links in a browser (Soti Surf) but this gives 2 problems.

### code

**HTML:**

```html
<div (click)="$ctrl.doTheThing()"> something </div>
```

**JS:**

```
private doTheThing() {
    this.inAppBrowser.create('surfs://' + url.replace(/^(https?:|)\/\//, ''), '_system');
}
```

### First issue

First of all when I use the android back button the click doesn't seem to work anymore (I've put an alert in the first line of the `doTheThing` function, but nothings shows up). 
Other buttons in the app seem to work just fine, when using the switch app button it also works

I tried:

- `preventDefault()`
- `stopPropagation()`
- using the `tappable` attribute
- `(tap)` instead of `(click)`

but none seem to work. Does anybody have an idea for fixing this?

### Second issue

*Note: this is less important*
When opening a link it remembers the last page(in soti surf) so by using the back arrow it first navigates to the last link and when it has no more back locations it goes back to the app

I tried:

- using the return value of the `inAppBrowser.create()` and calling `close()` when returning to my app

### Version info

- @ionic-native/core version: 4.16.0
- cordova-android: 7.1.4
- `cordova -v`: 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
- `npm -v`: 6.4.1
- `ionic`: 4.12.0
- nodeJS: 11.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Here in ionic you can prevent device back button by using `Navbar` Class and using  Lifecycle hook method

Here is a sample

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.navBar.backButtonClick = (e: UIEvent) => {
        // todo something
         if (condition ) 
        {
            this.getSaveDialog();
        } else{
                this.navCtrl.pop();
        }
    })
 }
```

For opening In **Appbrowser** in your app, will lose control of your events, you can't track and manage the 
state of pages.
It can be maintain by browser. you need to place hacks or alternative in your application which is opening in APP

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just wondering why I have different behaviour depending on how the come back to my app when using the back arrow or any other way. A hack seems wrong because it doesn't feel like this should even happen